# Wrye Bash problem: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified... Bashed Patch, 0.esp

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues, mods

I've been trying to use Wrye Bash (launched through Mod Organizer 1.3.8) to create a bashed patch. The process gets all the way to the end but then throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bash\basher.pyo", line 7068, in Execute
File "bash\bosh.pyo", line 3288, in refresh
File "bash\bolt.pyo", line 1207, in ctime
File "genericpath.pyo", line 64, in getctime
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\My Games\\Steam\\SteamApps\\common\\Skyrim\\Data\\Bashed Patch, 0.esp'
```

**Edit:** note that this error is produced by Wrye Bash and is opened in another window named: **wxPython: stdout/stderr**

I copied the template in the Mopy folder, pasted it into the Data folder, and renamed it "Bashed Patch, 0.esp" as I saw suggested on a different thread but that did not seem to do anything.

Checking the overwrite folder in Mod Organizer, it seems there is a Batched Patch, 0.esp that is 240kb. That seems kind of small and I would imagine that the batched patch creation process is supposed to actually finish instead of throwing an error.

In case it helps, here is my load order as well (which likely has some issues; also note that this is before running any of the patchers for PerMa, ASIS, or DSR as that is what the tutorials said to do):

```
  0  0 Skyrim.esm
  1  1 Update.esm
  2  2 Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp
  3  3 Dawnguard.esm
  4  4 Unofficial Dawnguard Patch.esp
  5  5 HearthFires.esm
  6  6 Unofficial Hearthfire Patch.esp
  7  7 Dragonborn.esm
  8  8 Unofficial Dragonborn Patch.esp
  9  9 Falskaar.esm
 10  a Wyrmstooth.esp
 11  b Cutting Room Floor.esp
 12  c Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp
 13  d Weapons & Armor Fixes_Remade.esp
 14  e Clothing & Clutter Fixes.esp
 15  f RaceMenu.esp
 16 10 RaceMenuPlugin.esp
 17 11 RaceMenuPluginXPMSE.esp
 18 12 AmazingFollowerTweaks.esp
 19 13 Auto Unequip Ammo.esp
 20 14 Brawl Bugs CE.esp
 21 15 RaceMenuMorphsCBBE.esp
 22 16 FollowerCompatibility.esp
 23 17 Hothtrooper44_Armor_Ecksstra.esp
 24 18 PermanentLegendaryBonus.esp
 25 19 SSoB.esp
 26 1a Unique Dragon Priest Masks.esp
 27 1b Headtracking.esp
 28 1c WetandCold.esp
 29 1d WetandCold - Ashes.esp
 30 1e SellThoseElderScrolls.esp
 31 1f Complete Crafting Overhaul_Remade.esp
 32 20 Undeath.esp
 33 21 Death Souls.esp
 34 22 dD - Realistic Ragdoll Force - Realistic.esp
 35 23 When Vampires Attack.esp
 36 24 PerkusMaximus_Master.esp
 37 25 PerMa Expansion 1 - Wintermyst.esp
 38 26 Pre PaMa WAFR CCOR Patch.esp
 39 27 Skyrim Immersive Creatures.esp
 40 28 Rebirth Monster.esp
 41 29 PermaZONESLegendaryBalanced.esp
 42 2a Combat Evolved.esp
 43 2b dD - Enhanced Blood Main.esp
 44 2c dD-Reduced Splatter Size.esp
 45 2d dD-Reduced Wound Size.esp
 46 2e RealShelter.esp
 47 2f RSPatch.esp
 48 30 SoS - The Wilds.esp
 49 31 OBIS.esp
 50 32 OBISDB.esp
 51 33 PerkusMaximus_Mage.esp
 52 34 Civil War Overhaul.esp
 53 35 SoS - Civilization.esp
 54 36 Thunderchild - Epic Shout Package.esp
 55 37 Skyrim Immersive Creatures - DLC2.esp
 56 38 SoS - The Dungeons.esp
 57 39 RealisticNeedsandDiseases.esp
 58 3a CCF_RND_Patch.esp
 59 3b dD-DG-DB-Immersive Creatures EBT Patch.esp
 60 3c Weightless Items - Potions (Beneficial).esp
 61 3d RND_Dawnguard-Patch.esp
 62 3e RND_Dragonborn-Patch.esp
 63 3f RND_USKP-Patch.esp
 64 40 DeadlyDragons.esp
 65 41 Thunderchild - Wyrmstooth Compatibility Patch.esp
 66 42 ShoutsRedragonized.esp
 67 43 Weapons & Armor_TrueWeaponsLvlLists.esp
 68 44 Immersive Weapons.esp
 69 45 WeaponsArmorFixes_ImmersiveWeapons_Patch.esp
 70 46 Hothtrooper44_ArmorCompilation.esp
 71 47 Inconsequential NPCs.esp
 72 48 Cloaks.esp
 73 49 Acquisitive Soul Gems.esp
 74 4a Run For Your Lives.esp
 75 4b SMIM-Merged-All.esp
 76 4c Immersive Patrols II.esp
 77 4d SkyUI.esp
 78 4e TradeBarter.esp
 79 4f More Interesting Loot for Skyrim.esp
 80 50 HothFollower.esp
 81 51 HothFollower UFO Patch.esp
 82 52 Chesko_Frostfall.esp
 83 53 RND_HearthFires-Patch.esp
 84 54 Drinking Fountains of Skyrim.esp
 85 55 FNISspells.esp
 86 56 RND_DrinkingFountains-Patch.esp
 87 57 1nivWICCloaks.esp
 88 58 1nivWICSkyCloaksPatch.esp
 89 59 Bandit Patrols.esp
 90 5a The Paarthurnax Dilemma.esp
 91 5b HoldBorderBanners.esp
 92 5c DragonPriestMaskQuestMarkers.esp
 93 5d Apocalypse - The Spell Package.esp
 94 5e Apocalypse - PerMa Compatibility Patch.esp
 95 5f Unique Unique.esp
 96 60 Pre PaMa SiC Patch.esp
 97 61 PerMaDefluffedPerkDescriptions.esp
 98 62 PerkusMaximus_Thief.esp
 99 63 Pre PaMa CCF Wintermyst Patch.esp
 100 64 Unique Uniques.esp
 101 65 TES5 Edit Merge Patch.esp
 102 66 Weightless Items - Scrolls.esp
 103 67 WeightlessPickaxeDB.esp
 104 68 weightlesspickaxe.esp
 105 69 Weightless Items - Alchemy Ingredients.esp
 106 6a WeightlessAxeReducedWood.esp
 107 6b Rebirth Monster - SIC Patch.esp
 108 6c CCF_Revenge of Enemies_Patch.esp
 109 6d RND_AnimalLoot.esp
 110 6e ASG Apocalypse Patch.esp
 111 6f ASG PerkusMaximus Patch.esp
 112 70 CCO_Frostfall_Patch.esp
 113 71 Inconsequential NPCs - CRF Compatibility Patch.esp
 114 72 Inconsequential NPCs - Enhancement.esp
 115 73 OBIS DG Faction Patch.esp
 116 74 OBISCloaks&IA7.esp
 117 75 Better Vampires.esp
 118 76 Cloaks - Dawnguard.esp
 119 77 PerkusRangedPatch.esp
 120 78 PerkusMaximus_Warrior.esp
 121 79 PerMaExtendedPerkDescriptions.esp
 122 7a Thunderchild - PerMa Compatibility Patch.esp
 123 7b PerMa_Survivalism.esp
 124 7c PerMa_USKP master patch.esp
 125 7d Wyrmstooth - PerMa Patch.esp
 126 7e Extended UI.esp
 127 7f iHUD.esp
 128 80 Dual Sheath Redux.esp
 129 81 Apocalypse-PerMa-DefluffedPerkDescriptions.esp
 130 82 Alternate Start - Live Another Life.esp
   Bashed Patch, 0.esp
 131 83 ASIS-Dependency.esp
```

Basically, I'm not really sure what the problem is since the Bashed Patch, 0 file is in the correct place.  If any additional information is needed, I can provide that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: The comma in the file name is bugging me. Have you tried without the comma and just put a `space` and maybe replace space by underscore `_` ? Putting space or special characters beside `A-z0-9_` is a bad practice in file renaming IMO.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't use spaces or commas but I figured since it specified that format, I'd use that. I tried `Bashed Patch 0.esp`, `Bashed_Patch_0.esp`, `Bashed Patch,_0.esp`, and `Bashed_Patch,_0.esp`. None of these worked. They all create a file in the overwrite mod that is ~220kb but I'm not sure if its a proper/useful patch since the process didn't actually finish.

Answer (score 1):

Based on these symptoms, I *suspect* the following:

1. You installed Wrye Bash Python edition, rather than standalone.
2. Your Python is 64-bit.
3. Mod Organizer can't do filesystem redirection for 64-bit applications.
4. Therefore it can't find the ESP file, and it dies.

Fortunately, the nice folks at S.T.E.P. have written a [detailed guide](http://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Mod_Organizer#Wrye_Bash) to making either version of Wrye Bash work correctly under Mod Organizer.  I recommend using the standalone version, because it does not require messing around with Python.  You just point Mod Organizer at the binary and go.

If you must use Python, make sure you install the *32-bit* version of Python (2.7.x, don't use 3.x because that's a whole different ball game).  https://www.python.org describes this as "Windows x86 MSI installer" once you click through to "Latest Python 2 release" from the [Windows downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).  The rest of your setup appears to work (or else you would not have gotten as far as you did), so you should only need to replace your Python interpreter.  Alternatively, you can switch to the standalone version of Wrye Bash and skip all of this nonsense.